# Which library can be used for this task queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to realize task queue with fixed timeout between start of each task and with overall callback, that called after all tasks ending. Does exist an appropriate library/package for Node.js?

[image: Queue chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a library. Assuming your tasks are available as an array of functions returning promises, then transform your promises to have a suitable initial delay:

```
promises = promises.map((promise, i) => wait(i * timeout).then(promise));
```

Then wait for them all to finish with `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(promises);
```

Here `wait` is something obvious such as

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

To wait for all promises regardless of settlement status:

```
promises = promises.map((promise, i) => wait(i * timeout).then(promise)
  .catch(reason => console.log("one rejected", reason, "continuing..."));
```

Comment: `Promise.all` fires on first rejected promise, how can I make it waiting for all to finish regardless of resolved or rejected promise?